# Variant of the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle

Tags: combinatorics, measure-theory, reference-request

I would like to know whether there is a short proof / known reference for the following fragment decomposition:

Let $(X, \mu)$ be a finite measure space. For any finite number of measureable sets $E_1, E_2, \dots, E_n \subseteq X$ we have
$$
\mu(\bigcup_{k=1}^n E_k) = \sum_{\emptyset \neq S \subseteq [n]} \mu\left(\bigcap_{k \in S} E_k \setminus \bigcup_{l \in [n]\setminus S} E_l \right),
$$
in which we denoted $\{1, \dots, n\}$ by $[n]$.

Answer (score 0):

It follows immediately from the additivity of $\mu$, because the collection of sets
$$\left\{\bigcap_{k \in S} E_k \setminus \bigcup_{l \in [n]\setminus S} E_l:\ S\subset[n]\text{ nonempty} \right\},$$
is a partition of $\bigcup_{k=1}^nE_k$ into finitely many parts.

---

*Proof.* Let $E:=\bigcup_{k=1}^nE_k$ and for every nonempty $S\subset[n]$ define
$$E_S:=\bigcap_{k \in S} E_k \setminus \bigcup_{l \in [n]\setminus S} E_l
\qquad\text{ and }\qquad
\mathcal{E}:=\{E_S:\ S\subset[n]\text{ nonempty}\}.$$
We want to show that $\mathcal{E}$ is a partition of $E$.
For every $x\in E$ define
$$S(x):=\{k\in[n]:\ x\in E_k\},$$
so that clearly $x\in E_{S(x)}$, which shows that $\mathcal{E}$ is a cover of $E$. Moreover, if $x\in E_S$ for some nonempty $S\subset[n]$ then $x\in E_k$ if and only if $k\in S$, which shows that $S=S(x)$. This shows that every $x\in E$ is contained in precisely one subset $E_S\in\mathcal{E}$, so $\mathcal{E}$ is a cover.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @Chris I have added a short proof; with the right notation it's almost a one-liner.